# Unknown host connecting to internet in ubuntu

Tags: linux

I tried to connect to my wifi network but i am not able to connect through my laptop .My other device at home are able to connect to internet. I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS . I set my browser proxy to no proxy . I have no antivirus installed .
I tried to ping -c 5 (google .com and facebook.com) in terminal its showing unknown host google.com and unknown host facebook.com and tried to install eclipse while downloading it shows error java error unknown host .
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [Superuser](http://superuser.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like DNS may not have been configured when you connected to the network.  This should normally happen automatically, but you can check by looking at the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.  There should be at least one line in the file containing `nameserver` and an IP address.

If there are no `nameserver` lines, or if there's only one and it says `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, then you can try to use Google's public DNS by adding the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (replacing the `127.0.0.1` if that's present).

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone, I had to face this issue. So what did I do to address this issue?

1) I configured my Ubuntu server to have two network interfaces (NAT and Intnet).

2) In `/etc/network/interfaces` , I added the following lines:

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 192.168.10.23
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

3) Restarted the network - `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

**Result**: `ping google.com` worked.

I hope this helps you in resolving this issue :)